# tf transform doc

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I found tf example says that "tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion ... " and it really works.
Why I seek the tf's api doc pages (classlist) in http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/c++/annotated.html,
it doesn't show the Transform class?
I only can find similar like Transformer,StampedTransform,... but no Transform.
So where is the doc page of tf::Transform?
I want to understand its parameters.
Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9949/tf-transform-doc/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some of the types in tf are nothing but typedefs for types in the Bullet library. You can see the correspondence here http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Overview/Data%20Types, and a Google search will give you details about the Bullet types.

---

Originally posted by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) with karma: 1071 on 2011-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4